# How to send a message from my app to a specific user messenger?

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net

How to send message to Facebook user inbox using ASP.NET 3.5 and C#? I am able to post the messages on walls using `fbAPI.Stream.Publish()` but I need to send a message to an inbox to be personal. Please guide me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i have a web application which sent a spacific code to the user whatsapp  ,message on his phone number and  to his gmail,
now i want to send this code to his facebook account
understand me?